# Using safe area layout in nib files but leave deployment target as iOS 8

Tags: ios, xcode, nib, safearealayoutguide

I've recently submitted my app to the app store after enabling Safe Area layout guide in anticipation of the iPhone X.

My app currently supports iOS 8 - so when I enabled the safe area layout guide on my nib file, i changed the 'build for' flag on the right hand side inspector to 9.0 rather than its previous 8 value.

What I forgot to do was update my targets 'deployment target' from 8.0 to 9.0.

Now my app is ready for release and I am unsure what the behaviour is going to be nor how I managed to get my nibs to be safe area compliant for iOS 9 and above but still be able to build and deploy to an iOS 8 device.

I've installed this app through test flight on an iOS 8.3 iPad and everything seems to be ok.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Thanks in advance,
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

Check again what have you sent to iTunes.

When I try to build my project with Safe Area and target iOS 8 I get `ibtool` build error

```
2017-10-20 18:18:58.787 ibtoold[51167:2585061] WARNING: Unhandled destination metrics: (null)
/* com.apple.ibtool.document.errors */
/Users/.../MySafeAreaViewController.xib:sf6-cB-C54: error: Safe Area Layout Guide before iOS 9.0
```

and I'm not able neither Debug nor Archive for upload to iTunes.

Comment: Thanks for the response Shebuka.

I've double checked what has been loaded to the app store and it is the build that I describe above. I am seeing no such error whether I use the Xcode build feature or archive. 

Simply the deployment target is 8.0 but the specific nib files I have changed to builds for 'iOS 9'.